# Seaborn not working as expected with matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot multiple seaborn regplots in matplotlib subplots like this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 5, ncols=3)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i in range(5):
    df1 = {'a': np.random.rand(100), 'b': np.random.rand(100)}
    df2 = {'a': np.random.rand(100), 'b': np.random.rand(100)}
    df3 = {'a': np.random.rand(100), 'b': np.random.rand(100)}
    sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,50)})
    sns.regplot(df1['a'], df1['b'], ax = axs[i])
    sns.regplot(df2['a'], df2['b'], ax = axs[i+1])
    sns.regplot(df3['a'], df3['b'], ax = axs[i+2])
```

However, instead of getting 15 subplots, I am getting 5 with data on top of each other in some odd combination. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong and optionally why the plots specifically look like this? [Example of what kind of plot I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkQwB.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: In the first loop run you fill axes 0,1,2. In the next you fill 1,2,3, etc in the last you fill 4,5,6. So axes 0 and 6 get one plot, 1 and 5 get two, 2 and 4 get three, and 3 gets four plots.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So essentially, my code isn't properly allocating plots?

Comment: Use `axs[i*3+n]` instead of `axs[i+n]` where `n=[0,1,2]`. It should work fine.

Comment: Or try `for i in range(0,15,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much qmaruf, your answer worked perfectly.

Here it is reproduced:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 5, ncols=3)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i in range(5):
    df1 = {'a': np.random.rand(100), 'b': np.random.rand(100)}
    df2 = {'a': np.random.rand(100), 'b': np.random.rand(100)}
    df3 = {'a': np.random.rand(100), 'b': np.random.rand(100)}
    sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,50)})
    sns.regplot(df1['a'], df1['b'], ax = axs[i*3])
    sns.regplot(df2['a'], df2['b'], ax = axs[i*3+1])
    sns.regplot(df3['a'], df3['b'], ax = axs[i*3+2])
```